# How can I pass some Data from another activity android

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass some data from one activity to another in my android app, however some errors occur when I try to run the code.
I'm passing data this way:

```
 Intent pod= new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putString("nume", NUME_VAL);
 extras.putString("prenume", PRENUME_VAL);
 startActivity(pod);
```

And recive this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
     String nume = data.getStringExtra("nume");
     String prenume = data.getStringExtra("prenume");
}
```

Comment: @Nilu I'm trying to do the same example but without success, thank you for sharing the link, had lost ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in how you send.

Add after `extras.putString("prenume", PRENUME_VAL);` the code: 
`pod.putExtras(extras);`

And to read on the second activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
     String nume = data.getStringExtra("nume");
     String prenume = data.getStringExtra("prenume");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 Intent pod= new Intent(YourActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putString("nume", NUME_VAL);
 extras.putString("prenume", PRENUME_VAL);
 pod.putExtras(extras);
 startActivity(pod);
```

instead of this

```
 Intent pod= new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now!

Comment: Welcome , please select my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

```
//Sending Data to another activity
Intent intent= new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
intent.putString("nume", NUME_VAL);
intent.putString("prenume", PRENUME_VAL);
startActivity(pod);
```

//Retrieving Data

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
String nume = data.getStringExtra("nume");
String prenume = data.getStringExtra("prenume");
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now!